# Automatic scroll not working for voice over in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm working on a SwiftUI Project where one my screen is having a scrollable content. I need to provide voice over support as well for these screens. My problem is when I keep swiping right, then the focus is moving to next element but it is not scrolling the content automatically.

My code something looks like this,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                   ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) {
                    Text("Text \($0)").font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                   }
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea on this?.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Ever find a solution?